# Difference between ようだ、見える and 見えます。

Tags: word-choice

Difference between ようだ、見える and 見えます。
I'm trying to say my dog looks like a cow.
All I've got so far is わたしの犬は牛
I've searched online and can't find a correct answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My dog looks like a cow! It is probably

> わたしの(かっている)犬は牛のようだ。

This sounds more like “My dog is like a cow.”

> 牛のように見える

is more precise but it would be odd for someone who is describing her/his dog. A stranger would give that type of comment.

This is better: __の__は__に[似]{に}ている。 Eg:

> わたしの犬は牛に似(に)ている。(My dog reassembles a cow.)